# getInitParameterNames() does not get init-parameters

Tags: java, servlets, web

I'm taking my first steps on web developing using servlets. Now I'm trying to retrieve some init-parameters of a servlet as well as context ones. They are declared on web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>JediWebTutorial</display-name>
    **<context-param>
        <param-name>contextParam</param-name>
        <param-value>contextValue</param-value>
    </context-param>**
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GreeterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jedi.servlets.GreeterServlet</servlet-class>
        **<init-param>
            <param-name>servletParam</param-name>
            <param-value>servletValue</param-value>    
        </init-param>**
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetParameterValuesServlet</servlet-name>
...
```

I'm trying to get it within the GreeterServlet, in the doGet method, like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    Enumeration<String> servletParams = config.getInitParameterNames();
    Enumeration<String> contextParams = context.getInitParameterNames();

    for (String param : Collections.list(servletParams)) {
        System.out.println(param);
    }

    for (String param : Collections.list(contextParams)) {
        System.out.println(param);
    }
...
```

As expected, console shows the name "contextParam". However, it does not print the "servletParam" name.

I'm struggling with it for hours and have assured that the  node is inside  and I'm not overriding init() method of GreeterServlet in any way (as it was reported as the cause of the problem in some cases on many discussion lists). I haven't found similar case on web - maybe for it's a too simple matter that I'm too beginer. Anyway, thanks for anybody who bother to take a look at it!

By the way, if helpful, I'm using TomCat 7.0.34 and Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 1):

Working on this problem I found that the init-parameters of a servlet can be accessed the following way (for the problem above):

```
ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
ServletRegistration register = context.getServletRegistration("GreeterServlet");
String servletParam = register.getInitParameter("servletParam");
System.out.println(servletParam);
```

what will print the expected *servletValue*.

It's indeed a solution, even though it does not answer the prior question. If anybody else come across with a similar problem, try it! And if anybody figure out the solution for the original problem, it will be still certainly wellcome! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I should have added this as comment, but somehow I am not getting "add comment" link for this question, hence posting as an answer.

Which servlet is the doGet() method you posted part of? It seems like it is part of GetParameterValuesServlet and you have added the init params to the GreeterServlet.

Comment: Thanks, but it's indeed the doGet method of GreeterServlet.

Comment: I used exactly the same code you have posted in the original post and got both "servletParam" and "contextParam" printed. I am not sure why you are not getting the same output.